# Sf map with bubble chart size included in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I can draw a map using `geom_point` that plots each point on a map with the size, colour and alpha each varying according to population (refer to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymlyn.png)). The legend correctly shows the size, colour and alpha associated with each of the breaks I have defined for population However, if I instead use `geom_sf` to draw the points (with all other code the same), then the legend does not display correctly. It only shows a rectangular box with the line adjusted to colour, with no changes in alpha or bubble size (refer to [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VRem.png)). Any ideas on how to resolve this? Code at the bottom of the post

**Legend Showing With Bubble Sizes Using geom_point**
[image: Using geom_point]

**Legened *Not* Showing Bubble Sizes Using geom_sf**
[image: Using geom_sf]

```
# Code using geom_point    
data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = map, aes(geometry=geometry), fill='#d5d5d2', colour=NA) +
  geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size=popM, color=popM, alpha=popM),
         shape=20, stroke=FALSE) +
  scale_size_continuous(name='Population (M)', trans='log',
                        range=c(1,12), breaks=mybreaks) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(name='Population (M)', trans='log',
                         range=c(0.1, .9), breaks=mybreaks) +
  scale_color_viridis(option="magma", trans="log", breaks=mybreaks,
                      name='Population (M)') +
  theme_void() + coord_sf() + 
  guides( colour = guide_legend()) +
  ggtitle('Cities With A Population Over 20 Thousand') +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.1, 0.25),
    text = element_text(color = '#22211d'),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = '#f5f5f2', color = NA), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#f5f5f2', color = NA), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = '#f5f5f2', color = NA),
    plot.title = element_text(size= 16, hjust=0.1, color = '#2e2d27',
                              margin = margin(b = -0.1, t = 0.4, l = 2,
                                              unit = 'cm'),
                              face = 'bold'),
  )

# For the second map, geom_point is replaced with this line
geom_sf(aes(geometry=geometry, size=popM, color=popM, alpha=popM),
             shape=20, stroke=FALSE) +
```

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273286/customize-legend-in-ggplot2-with-sf-objects can help you?